# Trying to link reviews users actively input under the show page of the specific movie for which the review was written

Tags: ruby-on-rails, parameters, redirecttoaction

Under app->controllers->reviews_controller.rb, I have the following code:

```
`def create
    review = Review.new
    review.movie_id = params["movie_id"]
    review.rating = params["rating"]
    review.content = params["content"]
    review.save
    redirect_to "/reviews"
 end
```

I think that I need to use this information to link a review a user makes in real time to the view page for the movie (just basically building a mini IMDB page with about 12 movies currently)app->views->movies->show.html.erb.

```
    <h2>Reviews</h2>
```

Do I need to use a params hash with "redirect_to" for the params["content"] above?

I hope this post is helpful to others seeking to gather user data and show in real time on the correct page.

This is reviews->index.

```
<h1>Reviews</h1>

<% for review in Review.order('created_at desc') %>

  <% movie = Movie.find_by(id: review.movie_id) %>
  <% if movie != nil %>

  <div class="row mb-3">
     <div class="col-sm-12">
     <div class="card">
         <div class="card-body">
          <h5 class="card-title">

            <% 1.times do %>
              <p>Howdy!</p>
            <% end %>

            &#9733; &#9733; &#9733; &#9733; &#9733; &#9733;
            <p>
              <%#= review.updated_at.strftime("%B %d, %Y %l:%M %P") %>
              <%= time_ago_in_words(review.updated_at) %> ago.
            </p>

            <h6 class="card-subtitle mb-2 text-muted">
              <%= movie.title %>
            </h6>
           </h5>
          <p class="card-text">
             <%= review.content %>
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>


    </div>
  </div>

 <% end %>
```

And this is the movies->show.

```
<% movie_id = params[:id] %>
<% movie = Movie.find_by(id: movie_id) %>

<div class="row">

   <div class="col-sm-6">
    <h2>
      <%= movie.title %>
    </h2>
  </div>

</div>

<div class="row">

  <div class="col-sm-3">
    <img src="<%= movie.poster_url %>" class="img-fluid">

  </div>

  <div class="col-sm-6">
    <a href="/movies/<%= movie.id %>/edit" class="float-right">
      <i class="fas fa-pen-square"></i>
      Edit This Movie
    </a>

    <% director = Director.find_by(id: movie.director_id) %>
    <% if director != nil %>
      <p>
        Directed by <%= director.name %>
      </p>
    <% end %>

    <p class="lead">
      <strong><%= movie.plot %></strong>
    </p>

    <div class="row mt-3">
      <% characters_in_this_movie = Character.where(movie_id: movie.id)   %>
      <% characters_in_this_movie.each do |character| %>

        <% the_actor = Actor.find_by(id: character.actor_id) %>

        <div class="col-sm-3 text-center">
          <%= image_tag(the_actor.photo_url, class: 'img-fluid mb-3') %>
          <br>
          <strong><%= the_actor.name %></strong>
          <br>
          as <%= character.name %>
        </div>

      <% end %>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>

<div class="row mt-5 justify-content-center">
  <div class="col-sm-6">
    <a href="/reviews/new?movie_id=<%= movie.id %>" class="float-   right">
      <i class="fas fa-pen-square"></i>
      Write a Review
    </a>

    <h2>Reviews</h2>


  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What's the question? the problem?

Comment: The problem is that you can enter a review for a movie and after clicking submit the website will accept the review but then not show it on each movie's page. All the reviews for all movies show up under a "Reviews" page. So I want to put each review on each movie's page. I guess using the movie's id with a params hash?

Comment: Then you should show us the `reviews#index` method and its view. You should also add `movies#show` method and its view (if you also want to show the reviews in the show for each movie).

Comment: Thank you, Pablo. I have added the code above. I appreciate your help.

Comment: @SebastianPalma and Pablo, could you give me some direction? Many thanks.